# Графика (рисунок по точкам) на Python

Tags: python, графика

Начала изучать питон с целью написания одного маленького приложения на вывод графических данных, поискала разный материал по языку и столкнулась с отсутствием литературы по работе с графикой на этом языке, но то, что она осуществляется, я знаю. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, литературу именно по конфигурированию и выводу графических данных.

Пока что мне нужно написать интересующее меня приложение в достаточно краткий срок, а потом уже буду глубже разбираться в языке.

---

Задача следующая -вывод на экран окна с текстом и двумя кнопками, при нажатии одной - вывод графических данных (т.е. отрисовка рисунка по точкам), при нажатии другой - вывод текстовых данных. И кнопка возврата к первоначальному окну. На этом всё.

хотелось бы решить её именно средствами python.

Comment: почему то все решили что вам нужны именно выдавать ГРАФИКИ. Уточните какую именно вы хотите решить задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Найдите библиотеку [graphics.py](http://graphics.py) она содержит примитивы на основе TK, которое уже есть в языке

Answer (score 1):

Если уж делать совсем по-простому, то я бы выбрал PyQt4. 3 строчки кода - остальное можно доделать на styleSheet как в html...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
label = QtGui.QLabel("img src='1.png'")
#если знать размер картинки
label.resize(100,100)
label.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib [link text](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib - стандартный выбор. А кроме того, графики и диаграммы:

- [Pychart](http://home.gna.org/pychart/)
- [CairoPlot](http://linil.wordpress.com/2008/06/14/cairoplot-plotting-graphics-using-python-and-cairo/)
- [Chaco](http://code.enthought.com/chaco/)
- [Python Google Chart](http://pygooglechart.slowchop.com/)
- [Pycha](http://www.lorenzogil.com/projects/pycha/)

Можно взять то, что покажется попроще, и смотреть примеры в документации.

Answer (score 0):

Списочек [Python GUI](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming). PyQt, например, уверен, позволит и не такое. 
Из этого списка наверное [EasyGui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/) - самый простой вариант. Но я не знаю, умеет ли она рисовать графики. Правда, вы можете сделать "финт ушами": нарисовать картинку и [запихнуть](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/download/version0.96/tutorial/index.html#contents_item_9) её в стандартное окошко.

UPD
А matplotlib, кстати, позволяет [кнопочки навигации размещать](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/navigation_toolbar.html), да и текс нарисовать не проблема

Comment: Боже мой... зачем мне графики )) Мне нужно нарисовать сердечко в окошке по одной кнопочке, текст сделать в другом )

Хотя можно ведь рассчитать так, чтобы график был сердечком.

Вообще какие ещё пути реализации видите для такой программки? Мне нужно-то всего лишь выразить таким образом симпатию к человеку. )

Comment: Тогда Вам не нужен Python, а подойдёт CHM. А вариант с EasyGui тоже решает эту проблему. В обоих случаях сердечко как раз просто картинка, которая изготавливается ручками в Paint, например.

Comment: кстати, хорошая идея :) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html

Comment: Не знаю, что проще тикля может быть для графики в Python.

Comment: По личным причинам, делать это лучше на питоне. ) Иначе бы я не задавала такой странный вопрос.

Спасибо всем за идеи, поизучаю. )

Comment: Так про него, про питона, и речь. tcl/tk был gui-стандартом де-факто до всяких gtk, qt и пр. В питоне давно живёт интерфейсная библиотека Tkinter (входит в стандартную поставку Python). Хотя на чистом tcl/tk данный гуй прикольней.